# 2D transformations by normal vector with eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am looking for a builtin way with the `eigen` library to perform coordinate transformations **by normal vectors** in 2D space.

Mathematically, it's not difficult: Let `v = (v_x, v_y)` be a 2D column vector and `n = (n_x, n_y)` be a normal vector, then the transformation I am looking for is one by rotational matrix:
`v_T = N * v`, with `v_T` being the transformed vector and `N` being the rotational matrix, which is

```
|  nx, ny |
| -ny, nx |
```

In my case, the data I need to transform is stored in an `Array2Xd` and the normal vectors are stored in a `Matrix2Xd`, with each column holding x- and y-component. I need to transform each column in the array by the corresponding normal vector in the matrix.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

/* transform a single vector, just for illustration */
Array2d transform_s( const Ref<const Array2d>& v, const Ref<const Vector2d>& n ){
    return {
        n.dot( v.matrix() ),
        -n.y() * v.x() + n.x() * v.y()
    };
}

/* transform multiple columns */
Array2Xd transform_m( const Ref<const Array2Xd>& v, const Ref<const Array2Xd>& n ){
    Array2Xd transformed ( 2, v.cols() );

    /* colwise dot product for first row */
    transformed.row(0) = (n * v).colwise().sum();
    /* even less elegant calculation for the second row */
    transformed.row(1) = n.row(0) * v.row(1) - n.row(1) * v.row(0);
    return transformed;
}

int main(){
    Array2Xd vals (2, 3);
    vals <<
        2, 0,-1,
        0, 3, 2;

    Matrix2Xd n;
    n.resizeLike(vals);
    n <<
        0, 0, 1, 
        1,-1, 1;
    n.colwise().normalize();

    std::cout
        << "single column:\n" << transform_s( vals.col(0), n.col(0) )
        << "\nall columns:\n" << transform_m( vals, n.array() )
        << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware of [`Eigen::Rotation2D`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Rotation2D.html), but it appears to either require an angle or a rotational matrix. I am specifically looking for a way to **only provide the normal vectors**. Otherwise I need to build the rotational matrices from the normal vectors myself, which doesn't really reduce the complexity on my end.

If there's no way to do this with `eigen`, I'll accept that as an answer. In that case, I'd be very happy about a more efficient implementation of what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is essentially a complex multiplication with `conj(n)`.

There is no elegant way to reinterpret a `Vector2d`/`Array2Xd` to a `complex<double>`/`ArrayXcd`, but you can hack something together using Maps:

```
Array2Xd transform_complex( const Ref<const Array2Xd>& v, const Ref<const Array2Xd>& n ){
    Array2Xd transformed(2, v.cols());

    ArrayXcd::Map(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(transformed.data()), v.cols())
       = ArrayXcd::Map(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double> const*>(v.data()), v.cols())
         *  ArrayXcd::Map(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double> const*>(n.data()), n.cols()).conjugate();
    return transformed;
}
```

You could write yourself a helper function which takes a `const Ref<const Array2Xd>&` and returns a `Map<ArrayXcd>` with the same content.

Comment: Is that safe when the ```const Ref<const Array2Xd>&``` is a ```Block``` with ```InnerPanel=false``` or an ```IndexedView```? I thought that ```Map``` expects contiguous memory, because we're just giving it a pointer and a size.

Comment: I can probably answer my comment myself: For ```Map```, one can specify a stride, so non-contiguous memory is fine, as long as it's regular. Not the same for ```IndexedView``` though.